# How to import specific excel range to datagridview

Tags: c#, gembox-spreadsheet

I want to import an excel file to datagridview using GemBox. Im fairly new to GemBox and I can't seem to figure out how. I only want to import from cell "A9" to cell "H32".

```
var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);

                DataGridViewConverter.ExportToDataGridView(workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet, this.dgvMain, new ExportToDataGridViewOptions() { ColumnHeaders = true });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can import specific cells:

```
var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;

var options = new ExportToDataGridViewOptions();
options.ColumnHeaders = true;
options.StartRow = 8;        // Start from row 9, index 8.
options.NumberOfRows = 24;   // End with row 32.
options.StartColumn = 0;     // start with column A, index 0.
options.NumberOfColumns = 8; // End with column H.

DataGridViewConverter.ExportToDataGridView(worksheet, this.dgvMain, options);
```

Also here is another way how you can specify the same, by using the properties from `CellRange` object:

```
var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;
var range = worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A9:H32");

var options = new ExportToDataGridViewOptions();
options.ColumnHeaders = true;
options.StartRow = range.FirstRowIndex;
options.NumberOfRows = range.Height;
options.StartColumn = range.FirstColumnIndex;
options.NumberOfColumns = range.Width;

DataGridViewConverter.ExportToDataGridView(worksheet, this.dgvMain, options);
```